Get information about a Sleeping CURSOR
I am detecting too much sleeping sessions on my SQL Server Instance, this sleeping sessions sometimes are causing blockages with other sessions.
The main problem is related with the Event info of this sleeping sessions because they are always CURSORS, like: FETCH API_CURSOR0000000001FF9XXX
I am using this query to get the sleeping sessions that are in this state more than 60 minutes.

SELECT 
    se.session_id,   
    event_info, 
    tr.transaction_begin_time, 
    se.database_id, 
    DB_NAME(se.database_id) as dbname,
    status, 
    se.open_transaction_count ,
    se.host_name,
    se.last_request_start_time,
    se.last_request_end_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions se
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions setr
    ON se.session_id = setr.session_id 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tr
    ON setr.transaction_id = tr.transaction_id
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(se.session_id , 0) as t1
WHERE 
    se.open_transaction_count > 0
    AND status = 'sleeping'
    AND is_user_process = 1
    AND se.last_request_start_time < DATEADD(SECOND, -5, CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime2(3)))
    AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, se.last_request_start_time, GETDATE()) > 60 
ORDER BY tr.transaction_begin_time;`

When I see the Eventinfo column, I see the CURSOR that is sleeping, but I need the information about the query that is causing this CURSOR.
FETCH API_CURSOR0000000001FF9XXX
¿How can i see this associated query to the cursor o what is causing this FETCH? I try with this query:
SELECT c.session_id, c.properties, c.creation_time, c.is_open, t.text

FROM sys.dm_exec_cursors (53) c

CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text (c.sql_handle) t


But is in sleeping mode and I cant take the information.

can you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 to see what kind of stuff it returns?
